# how to invalidate another session in worklight

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst

Customer want to restrict duplicate login for the App, once user login from another phone, the session of previous phone should be invalidated.

but I can't find the API for worklight to do this, besides using push, another suggestions? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight indeed does not provide any API for this type of scenario.

Here is what I am thinking as an example of what can be done:

- Device #1 is an Asus, device #2 is an LG
- As the user log-ins, you will store the device information in the Worklight database (using [WL.Client.setUserPref](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23setUserPref))
- When the user will try to log-in again from another device, you could pull the existing pref (using [WL.Client.getUserPref](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23getUserPref)) and compare the device types
- If they are not the same, logout current userId and re-login
- (Consult the user documentation for additional API methods around userpref)

This could be a way to ensure the user is logged only from one device.
You could also use the userId associated with the deviceId and update upon every login `if (currentDeviceId != latestDeviceId) logout();` and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. but when user login using another device, it'll be another new session in WL server, how can WL adapter logout the previous session? if call logout directly, it only apply to the new session.

Comment: Idan Adar Please suggest solution for this. Need solution for this as 2 devices should not able to login together. If one device is not logged out, other device should be authenticated untill previous device is logged out

Answer (score 0):

Here I have posted a implementation mechanism which strikes in my mind.

Its still a suggestion.

1. Whenever a user tries to login an entry can be made in backend[DB/Webserice] which tells about the user/device information.
2. If the user info is existing already then you can prompt a dialog box to the user ***The account has been logged in already, if you continue to login the previous session would be logged out*** trigger a push notification to the previously logged in user device, if user continues.
3. Now a notification will be reached to previously logged in device. Here you can implement the logic to execute the **WL.Client.logout(realm, options)**.

It would be great if someone post answer better than what I did.

And also let me know if my suggestion was helpful or not.